# If I click order form it should display and other form should hide

Tags: javascript, html

In this code, if I click the order details, that form should display, and if I click the shipping details address that form should display and the order form should hide.
However here both the forms are displaying in my code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <script>
         function orderdetails() {
    document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "block";
       }
         function shippingdetails() {
     document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "block";
       }
         function ordersummary() {
          document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "block";
           }
          function payment() {
          document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "block";
            }   
     </script>
     </head>

     <body>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" value="Show Div" onclick="orderdetails()" >Order                                               Details</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" value="Show Div1" onclick="shippingdetails()">Shipping             Details</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <a href="javascript:void(0);" value="Show Div12" onclick="ordersummary()">Order Summary</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" value="Show Div12" onclick="payment()">Payment</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

       <div id="orderdetails"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > 
          <table width="200" border="0">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <h3><u><b>Order Details</b></u></h3>
             <tr>
           <th scope="row"><label>Name*</label></th>
         <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <th scope="row"><label>Email*</label>;</th>
             <td><input name="mail" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
              <th scope="row"><label>Mobile Number*</label></th>
         <td><input name="mobile" type="text"></td>
             </tr>
           <tr>
           <th scope="row"><label>Land Line</label></th>
           <td><input name="phone" type="text"></td>
           </tr>

        </table>

       </div>
          <div id="shippingdetails"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > 
           <br/>
             <table width="200" border="0">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <h3><u><b>Shipping Details</b></u></h3>
               <br/>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Full Name*</label></th>
            <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
           </tr>
          <tr>
               <th scope="row"><label>Address*</label></th>
         <td><textarea name="address" cols="" rows=""></textarea></td>
         </tr>
           <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>Nearest Land Mark*</label>;</th>
           <td><input name="mail" type="text"></td>
          </tr>

         <tr>
            <th scope="row"><label>City</label></th>
           <td><input name="city" type="text"></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
             <th scope="row"><label>State</label></th>
          <td><form name="form" id="form">
           <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
    <option>Tamil Nadu</option>
    <option>Kerala</option>
    <option>Orissa</option>
    <option>Delhi</option>
    <option>Andhrs</option>
    <option>Karntaka</option>
  </select>
</form></td>
   </tr>
         <tr>
         <th scope="row"><label>Pin Code*</label></th>
        <td><input name="code" type="text"></td>
               </tr><tr>
          <th scope="row"><label>Mobile Number*</label></th>
          <td><input name="city" type="text"></td>
          </tr><tr>
           <th scope="row"><label>Land Line</label></th>
           <td><input name="city" type="text"></td>
     </tr>
       </table>
     </div>

     </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You need to add ....display="none" to each. Also return false and `onclick="return ...details()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't just display the form, hide the others as well.

```
function orderdetails() {
    document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "none";
}
function shippingdetails() {
    document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "none";
}
```

To prevent users from going back to the previous form, you can check if they have completed that particular form.

In your form, give the required items a class name:

```
<input name="name" type="text" class="order-required">
<input name="mail" type="text" class="order-required">
<input name="mobile" type="text" class="order-required">
```

And give the "Order Details" link an ID:

```
<a id="orderdetailslink" href="javascript:void(0);" value="Show Div" onclick="orderdetails()" >Order Details</a>
```

Then put down the following before `</body>` to look for all the required fields in "Ordering Details":

```
<script>
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i, orderRequired = new Array();
for (i in elems) {
    if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + 'order-required' + ' ') > -1) {
        orderRequired.push(elems[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally use the following functions to check if the user should be allowed to go back to the ordering details form.

```
function orderdetailscomplete() {
    for (var i = 0; i < orderRequired.length; i++) {
        if (orderRequired[i].value.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function orderdetails() {
    if (!orderdetailscomplete()) {
        document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "none";
    }
}
function shippingdetails() {
    document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "none";
    if (orderdetailscomplete()) {
        document.getElementById('orderdetailslink').innerHTML = 'Order Details (completed)';
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zMrN/embedded/result/).

Comment: hi, after i finishing the order detaila and click continue the shipping must display,its all working fine but i dont want to go to order details again .if i click i should not come. plz help me.

Comment: i cant get it please explain me clearly or code it clearly...what i am asking means after i complete filling the order details i will continue with shipping details.... if i click order details means it must show as cross mark or some thing that it must indicate that has been completed

Comment: @Arivazhagan I have explained and coded these very clearly. These go to the basic understanding of programming. I suggest you try some tutorials and learn more about JavaScript. See the updated answer. It should do what you're asking for.

Comment: please help me. in above updated code without completing order details i should not proceed with the shipping address and so on. for that what i should do..

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the script, your html is seriously malformed. You really need to read up on html. http://validator.w3.org/check cannot even continue checking until you move that header out of the table code

Here is my version.
Checked and fixed the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Order form</title>  
<script>
var divs = [];
function show(div) {
  for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display=(div===divs[i])?"block":"none"; 
  }        
}
function MM_jumpMenu() {} // placeholder

window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("jumpMenu").onchange=function() {
    MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0);
  }
  var links=document.getElementById("navigation").getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
    divs.push(links[i].id.replace("link",""));
    links[i].onclick=function() {
      show(this.id.replace("link",""));
    }
  }    
}
</script>         
  <style>
  ul#navigation {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  ul#navigation li { display: inline; }
  ul#navigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .25em 1em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #39f;
    border-top: solid 1px #39f;
    border-right: solid 1px #39f;
  }
  a:link, a:visited { color: #fff; }
  ul#navigation li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#000;
  }
  .shipping { width:200px; border:0}
  </style>
  </head>         
  <body> 
  <nav>       
    <ul id="navigation">  
      <li><a href="#" value="Show Div"   id="orderdetailslink">Order Details</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#" value="Show Div1"  id="shippingdetailslink">Shipping Details</a></li>             
      <!--li><a href="#" value="Show Div12" id="ordersummarylink">Order Summary</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#" value="Show Div12" id="paymentlink">Payment</a></li -->
    </ul>
  </nav>              
    <div id="orderdetails"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >
    <br/>
    <h3><u><b>Order Details</b></u></h3>  
      <table class="shipping">            
        <tr> 
          <th scope="row"><label>Name*</label></th>
          <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <th scope="row"><label>Email*</label>
          </th>
          <td><input name="mail" type="text"></td>  
        </tr> 
        <tr>    
          <th scope="row"><label>Mobile Number*</label></th>
          <td><input name="mobile" type="text"></td></tr> 
        <tr> 
          <th scope="row"><label>Land Line</label></th>
          <td><input name="phone" type="text"></td></tr>              
      </table>           
    </div>
    <div id="shippingdetails"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >   
      <br/>   
     <h3><u><b>Shipping Details</b></u></h3>     
      <table class="shipping">
        <tr>  
          <th scope="row"><label>Full Name*</label></th>
          <td><input name="name" type="text"></td></tr>
        <tr>     
          <th scope="row"><label>Address*</label></th>
          <td><textarea name="address"></textarea></td>             
        </tr> 
        <tr>  
          <th scope="row"><label>Nearest Land Mark*</label></th> 
            <td><input name="mail" type="text"></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>  
          <th scope="row"><label>City</label></th>
          <td><input name="city" type="text"></td> 
        </tr>  
        <tr>   
          <th scope="row"><label>State</label></th>
          <td>
            <form name="form" id="form"> 
              <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu">        
                <option>Tamil Nadu</option>        
                <option>Kerala</option>        
                <option>Orissa</option>        
                <option>Delhi</option>        
                <option>Andhrs</option>        
                <option>Karntaka</option>      
              </select>    
            </form></td>       
        </tr>             
        <tr>             
          <th scope="row"><label>Pin Code*</label></th>
          <td><input name="code" type="text"></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><label>Mobile Number*</label></th>
          <td><input name="city" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <th scope="row"><label>Land Line</label></th>
          <td><input name="city" type="text"></td>         
        </tr>           
      </table>         
    </div>         
  </body>          
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a code which will hide opened forms. You may do it like this:

```
function closeAll() {
     document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "none";
}
function orderdetails() {
   closeAll();
   document.getElementById('orderdetails').style.display = "block";
}
function shippingdetails() {
     closeAll();
     document.getElementById('shippingdetails').style.display = "block";
}
function ordersummary() {
   closeAll();
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "block";
}
function payment() {
    closeAll()
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "block";
}
```

See closeAll function which hides all divs. Just in order to not look for opened div. I'm closing welcomeDiv1 also. Not sure if you need that.

Comment: ShowOnly with a test on passed div to show would be more elegant

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to show one form at a time, you should hide them initially and show only the first one to appear.

Then in every function you should hide the others. FAngel has the better solution so far.

Two tips:

1. Remove all those blank spaces (&nbsp) and try and use some css.
2. And for javascript I recomend you use some js frameworks such as jQuery.

Good Luck!

Comment: For this little amount of JS, there is absolutely no need for jQuery

Comment: I know, but it looks like he's building an e-commerce system. Not just this page. And the sooner he learns, the better. Except if he's a purist and wants to use only ECMAScript.